# How to change single custom post template by custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

Working on a publication (wordpress based) website, having a custom post type "article" with custom taxonomy : language (with only two options: French, English). I made a custom post type template (single-article-french.php) for only French language articles (English ones will be displayed using the single-cpt.php template).
How can i make wordpress change automatically the template of my custom post type to single-article-french.php when the language of the article is set to French?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do, is have your default `single-article.php`. This will get called by default because of the WP permalinks and templating system.

At the top of your `single-article.php` do the following before your `get_header()` call:

```
<?php
$language = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'language' );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $language) && $language && 'French' == $language[0]->name ) {
    get_template_part( 'single-article-french' );
} else {
    // english template stuff
    get_header();
    // etc.
}
```

That way you will call `single-article-french.php` when the French category is selected.

Comment: thanks for your response. i got this : Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in this line: `if ( count( $language ) && 'French' == $language[0]->name ) {` .

Comment: We better add the `is_wp_error( $language )` check as well, just in case.  @nisr Most likely you got this error because it should be `get_the_terms()` instead of `get_terms()`. But then we must be careful here with `count( $language )` for no terms, because `count( false )` is `1` !! ;-)

Comment: thanks @birgire. can you give your full suggested code please?

Comment: it worked perfectly .. thanks a lot @birgire and thanks to Eric

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup, @birgire, this answer was pre-coffee :).